# Linux kernel patch

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, terminology

I am reading "Linux kernel module programming" by Peter Jay Salzman, and in that book they say

> sys_call_table is no longer exported in 2.6.x kernels.
>   If you really want to try this DANGEROUS module you will
>   have to apply the supplied patch against your current kernel
>   and recompile it.

Can anybody explain the meaning of "patch" to me, and what it means to recompile the kernel.

Comment: Just source code patch, a set of file that records all the changes of the kernel source code.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 can you please elaborate more. And why do we the patch ?

Comment: Because we want to change the sourse code?

Answer (score 7):

A "patch" is a file describing changes to another file (the file can be anything including source code). One of the simplest ways to create and use a patch is with `diff` and `patch`.

Let's say we have a simple hello world program in a file called `hello1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now let's change the string `"Hello world!\n"` to `"Hi world!\n"` and call the new program `hello2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hi world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now in a terminal run the following command:

```
diff -u hello1.c hello2.c > hello-patch
```

Outputting the content of the patch file with `cat hello-patch` shows this:

```
--- hello1.c    2019-03-18 13:29:35.897546888 -0500
+++ hello2.c    2019-03-18 13:30:02.866456737 -0500
@@ -2,6 +2,6 @@

 int main(void)
 {
-  printf("Hello world!\n");
+  printf("Hi world!\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

This file indicates changes between `hello1.c` and `hello2.c`.

Now let's say you've distributed the source code for `hello1.c` to your friends. This `hello-patch` patch file allows your friends to transform `hello1.c` into `hello2.c` with the patch command. If `hello1.c` and patch are in the same directory, this command:

```
patch < hello-patch
```

This will "apply the patch to `hello1.c`". When it's done, `hello1.c` will be updated and it is now identical to `hello2.c`.

So patches are just *lists of changes to a file (or set of files)*, and these patches allow someone to selectively update a file by applying patches.

The `diff` and `patch` commands work well for small patches. Anything big and complicated will need an industrial strength tool. Linux uses `git`. The `git` help system is pretty good. For instance, `git help -a` lists all `git` help topics, and `git help format-patch` details how to "Prepare patches for e-mail submission".

Linux development is carried out via email, and you can view an archive of the emails sent by linux developers at [lkml.org](https://lkml.org/), and [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/) is a great starting place for learning about Linux kernel development. Be warned, since it looks like the book you cite was published in 2009, some of the technical details it contains will be out of date.

"Recompiling" in this case just means compiling again after applying the patch to the source. It's like when you run something like `gcc hello1.c -o hello` to compile a source file into executable code. [This guide describes building Linux](https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild). [This one describes a build process with some steps that can be used on the Debian distribution](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-building-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel/).

[This 2016 talk by Linux developer Greg Kroah-Hartman gives an overview of what Linux development is like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyenmLqJQjs)

Comment: on what basis changes are decided ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what "recompile the kernel" and "apply a patch means", you should read other Linux/Unix-related books that covers more basic topics instead of taking your time trying to get knowledge from a book that is specific for Linux Kernel development like "Linux kernel module programming" by Peter Jay Salzman.

I suggest you the following books(sorry if it this post looks like an AD) to start your journey to aquire knowledge on how to operate a Unix-like OS:

- **UNIX and Linux System Administration Handbook, 4th Edition** by Evi Nemeth (Author), Garth Snyder (Author), Trent R. Hein (Author), Ben Whaley (Author)
- **How Linux Works: What Every Superuser Should Know** by Brian Ward
- **The Cathedral and the Bazaar: Musings on Linux and Open Source by an Accidental Revolutionary** by Eric S. Raymond